# Nodejs Mongoose 'Operation `XXX.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

`index.ts` is the entry point of this NodeJS program.

This is the code in `index.ts`:

```
import JobWorker from "./worker";
import { SwitchPlan } from "./jobs";

const worker = new JobWorker();
worker.addJob(SwitchPlan);
```

This is `worker.ts`:

```
import { CronJob } from "cron";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Config from "./config";
import logger from "./logger";

export default class JobWorker {
    private jobs: CronJob[];
    private config: {
        NAME: string;
        MONGO_URL: string;
    };

    constructor() {
        this.config = Config;
        this.connectDB();
        this.jobs = [];
    }

    public async connectDB(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await mongoose.connect(this.config.MONGO_URL,
                { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true },
            );
            logger.info("\nMONGODB has been connected\n");
        } catch(err) {
            logger.error("ERROR occurred while connecting to the database");
        }
    }

    addJob(cronJob: CronJob) {
        this.jobs.push(cronJob);
    }
}
```

This is `jobs.ts`:

```
import moment from "moment";
import { 
    DatabaseOperations, Vehicle,
    Plan1Doc, Plan1, VehicleDoc 
} from "common-lib";
import logger from "../logger";
import { CronJob } from "cron";

const vehicleOps = new DatabaseOperations(Vehicle);

const SwitchPlan = new CronJob("25 * * * * *", async (): Promise<void> => {

    const date: Date = moment(new Date()).startOf("date").toDate();
    const expiringVehicles: VehicleDoc[] = vehicleOps.getAllDocuments(
        {   "inspection.startTime": { 
                "$gte": date, "$lte": moment(date).startOf("date").add(1, "day").toDate() 
            }
        },
        {}, { pageNo: 0, limit: 0 }
    ).then((result: any) => {
        logger.info("dsada");
    }).catch((err: any) => {
        logger.info("ssd");
    });

});

SwitchPlan.start();

export { SwitchPlan };
```

I have omitted parts of code which are irrelevant to this problem. I ran this code through a debugger and there's no issue with the config. MonggoDB connected is getting printed at the start of the program. However the `then` block after `getAllDocuments` in `jobs.ts` is never reached and it always goes in the error block with the message, `Operation` vehicleinventories.find() `buffering timed out after 10000ms`. The `getAllDocuments` uses MongoDB's `find()` method and is working correctly because I am using this method in other projects where I have no such issues.

So far I have tried, deleting Mongoose from node_modules and reinstalling, tried connecting to MongoDB running on localhost, but the issue remains unsolved.

EDIT: DatabaseOperations class:

```
import { Model, Schema } from "mongoose";
class DatabaseOperations {
  private dbModel: Model<any>;

  constructor(dbModel: Model<any>) {
    this.dbModel = dbModel;
  }

  getAllDocuments(
    query: any,
    projections: any,
    options: { pageNo: number; limit: number },
    sort?: any
  ): any {
    const offset = options.limit * options.pageNo;
    return this.dbModel
      .find(query, projections)
      .skip(offset)
      .limit(options.limit)
      .sort(sort ? sort : { createdAt: -1 })
      .lean();
  }
}
```

Comment: you did connect with mongoose, but what is this `CrudOperations`? What if you replace inventoryCrudOps.getAllDocuments with a normal mongoose model find operation?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Its a class which has all methods for basic CRUD operations on a Mongoose model. As I said, in my post, that part of code is well tested and I have been using it in many different projects. I will add some parts of it in the question.

Comment: the main question is, did you try replacing `const inventoriesToExpire: VehicleInventoryDoc[] = inventoryCrudOps.getAllDocuments` with a normal `mode.find` query and see if it's working? That will isolate at the very minimium, whether it's a problem with mongoose codes or your class codes.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Yes I just tried it, still getting the same error. EDIT: I did `const temp = VehicleInventory.find().then((result: any) => {})` and commented out `const inventoriesToExpire: VehicleInventoryDoc[] = inventoryCrudOps.getAllDocuments`

Answer (score 1):

in your `jobs.ts` file you have the following line

```
SwitchToTier1Plan.start();
```

This line is called the moment you required the class file, hence before mongoose is connected, and all the models defined. Could this be the issue?

Another thing I noted is u are using `mongoose.connect` which may be wrong since `mongoose.connect` creates a global connection.

which means each `new Worker` you will be attempting to override the mongoose property with previous connection

Though i'm not sure what the implication is, but it could be because your .find could be using the old connection.

Since you are writing class, I would recommend using `mongoose.createConnection` which creates a new connection for each class initiation.

Comment: I just ran it through the debugger and found that `SwitchToTier1Plan.start();` is indeed running before MongoDB is connected. So most likely this was the cause of this error.

Comment: But `SwitchToTier1Plan.start();` does not involve any MongoDB operations. `start` is a method from `cron` node package which just starts a job.

Comment: Got the same error even after I removed `SwitchToTier1Plan.start();` from the module and instead added it to `index.ts` after creating the Worker object.

Comment: I share a little about `mongoose.createConnection` if you want to go research on it and give it a try. Writing classes, mongoose.connect definitely not the way to go.

Comment: Worker is being used as a singleton, there will always be just instance of it. Moreover, even in the current code, there's just one instance of it.

Comment: Then where did u declare your schemas?

Comment: VehicleInventory is my mongoose model and I have imported it in `jobs.ts` from a package I created locally and linked it using `npm link`.

Comment: well u look into that. You have your own way of creating those schema and connections. What I think is, your .find is not using your mongoose connection. Or should I say, your model is not using the mongoose connection. For example, your `mongoose.model('Model', schema)` is not using the same mongoose object since you using a npm package